# VBA code for if value is < value 1 cell ago in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for VBA code.

If any random cell in a column is less than the previous cell in the same column, then place "A" in column E.

i.e.

```
Column D    Column E
.01112      A
.01114
.01113
.01112      A
.01114
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ATest()



Dim rngCell As Range, _
        rngDataRange As Range

    Set rngDataRange = Range("D1:D5000")

    rngDataRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = rngDataRange.Value

    For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
        With rngCell

            If .Value > 0.1 And .Value < 0.5 Then
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = .Value 'A[rngCell] to C[rngCell]
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: you do not need VBA code for that. you can use a cell formula

Comment: .01113 is less than .01114 ... why is there no `A` next to .01113?  .... why is there an `A` next to .01112 when there is no previous cell

Comment: It moves from bottom to top not top to bottom.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you are using a sequence that is opposite to convention? ... when you add rows of data to a worksheet, the "next" row is always the higher numbered row, and the "previous" row is the one that is lower numbered row ..... or is it just the wording that you chose to use? .... fyi: it creates an unnecessary language uncertainty.

Comment: Hello thank you for your email. I do this because the sheet is always updating and it is easier for me to read from the top instead of scrolling down to the bottom.

Comment: makes total sense. i wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample implies that you actually want to place an "A" in column E if the value is less than the value on the **next** row, so an extra `If` statement added into your code will do that:

```
Sub ATest()
    Dim rngCell As Range, _
        rngDataRange As Range

    Set rngDataRange = Range("D1:D5000")

    'This statement doesn't seem to be desired if you want to put the "A"
    'in column E
    'rngDataRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = rngDataRange.Value

    For Each rngCell In rngDataRange
        With rngCell

            If .Value > 0.1 And .Value < 0.5 Then
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = .Value 'A[rngCell] to C[rngCell]
            End If
            If .Value < .Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = "A"
            End If
        End With
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,thankyou fr the reply. It is not the next row but within the same column; also the sequence moves from the bottom to the top not top to bottom.

Comment: So, if it "moves from bottom to the top" you **do** want to check whether each cell's value is less than the value of the cell in the row below.  So the code in the answer should work.  (But I'm not sure what you mean by "It is not the next row but within the same column" - if it is in the same column then the only thing you can be comparing is values on different rows of that column, so how can it not be two sequential rows being compared?)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. Yes you are correct, I want to compare different rows in the same column. The newest date is at the top of the column i.e. A2 and the oldest date is at the bottom i.e. A10934